# Azure Shared Device Registration Failed

Tags: android, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to test shared device mode on Android. I'm following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-shared-device-mode#set-up-an-android-device-in-shared-mode) and have gotten as far as the device registration stage.

However, I'm getting an error in the Authenticator app when trying to register the device for shared device mode: `Shared device registration failed. Contact your admin if the issue continues. Error: User is not authorized for registration.`

[image]

According to the docs I should need the Cloud Device Administrator role assignment to perform this action, which I do:

[image]

I have tried to find more information about this, to no avail:

[image]

Has anyone done this successfully? What configuration am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue occurred because the **Cloud Device Administrator role does not work for guest accounts**. Trying again with an account native to the tenant worked. This appears to be an undocumented requirement.

Answer (score 0):

### Note:

This won't work for **guest accounts** with Cloud Device Administrator role. Make sure to assign this role to local accounts (Azure AD accounts) in your tenant.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I created 2 **Azure AD users** in my tenant i.e., one **with** Admin roles (Sri Admin):

[image]

You can find the **`UPN`** of **Sri Admin** user here:

[image]

I created another user **without** Admin roles (Sri Non-Admin) like below:

[image]

You can find the **`UPN`** of **Sri Non-Admin** user here:

[image]

To set up Android device in **shared mode**, I followed same steps from this [**MS Doc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-shared-device-mode#set-up-an-android-device-in-shared-mode).

When I signed-in with **Sri Non-Admin** account, I got the **same error** as you like below:

[image]

But when I signed-in with **`Sri Admin`** account, Shared Device Mode **enabled** successfully as below:

[image]

When I checked the same in Portal, I got the **shared device** listed like below:

[image]

You can confirm whether it's the same device or not by checking its **device ID** in properties:

[image]

In your case, make sure whether you are signing in with **same UPN** of user with assigned roles or not.

Comment: Thanks for putting this effort in. I am signing in with the account that is assigned the Cloud Device Administrator role.

Comment: Could you confirm whether that account is **Azure AD account** or not, that ends with `onmicrosoft.com`?

Comment: Azure AD account ending with something else. Upon investigation it seems that a guest account can't do it, even if assigned the cloud device administrator role. A local account from the tenant can. Undocumented requirement?

Comment: You are correct, it's not documented yet. Check the updated answer

Comment: If you update your answer to primarily highlight your update (as that is actually the answer to my question) I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249607/discussion-between-sridevi-and-matt-g).